# Java instance variable visibility (ThreadLocal)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, visibility, thread-local

In the class [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://xref.jsecurity.net/openjdk-6/jdk/d2/dcb/_reentrant_read_write_lock_8java-source.html) is the following curious comment:

```
transient ThreadLocalHoldCounter readHolds;

Sync() {
    readHolds = new ThreadLocalHoldCounter();
    setState(getState()); // ensures visibility of readHolds
}
```

what does it mean by "ensures visibility"? The reason I ask is that I have a situation where it looks as though the thread local readHolds is being reset (thread locals are implemented as WeakReferences so that shouldn't happen as long as the containing Sync object is still alive). setState/getState simply alter another instance variable and don't touch readHolds.

Comment: Can you show setState()/getState()?

Comment: There is an example here: http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer-source.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setState(int)` method performs an assignment to a volatile variable. This causes any assignments performed by the current thread—including readHolds—to be flushed to "main memory".

Other threads calling `getState()` read this same volatile variable. Since the variable is volatile, the thread's cache is cleared first, forcing subsequent read operations to go out to main memory, where they will find the most recent value of `readHolds`.

Comment: "*any* assignments performed by the current thread—including readHolds—" are flushed. It doesn't matter if the other writes are to a volatile variable; if they come before the write to the volatile variable in the source code, they are flushed along with the volatile variable. This is one of the key changes to the Java Memory Model that occurred in Java 5.